# How to add multiple item in IList C# with UnitTest

Tags: c#, list, unit-testing

So here is my object classes

```
public class OrderModel
{
    public IList<ListCartTest> Cart { get; set; }

    public OrderModel()
    {
        Cart = new List<ListCartTest>();
    }
}

public class ListCartTest
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public double amount { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }

}
```

and here is my unit test code, i want to add a new cart item inside that list

```
 [Test]
    public void TestOrder()
    {
        var entity = new OrderModel();
        string tokenAdmin = "tokentestt";


        var cart = new ListCart();
        cart.name = "Mineral Water";
        cart.amount = 3;
        cart.price = 3000;
        entity.Cart.Add(cart);

        var cart = new ListCart();
        cart.name = "Fried Rice";
        cart.amount = 2;
        cart.price = 6000;
        entity.Cart.Add(cart);

        var result = _order.InsertOrder(tokenAdmin, entity);

        Assert.AreEqual(result.Status, true);
    }
```

i am a newbie i dont know how to add item in this list, can anyone help and teach me ????

Comment: Which list is "this list"? You're adding an item just fine: `entity.Cart.Add(cart);`

Comment: the 2nd , i want to add multiple item to that list sir

Comment: Sorry, you have to be more specific. I don't know which "the 2nd" list is. Please [edit] your question and describe which line of code you are having trouble with and also describe what exactly the problem is.

Comment: i just want to add more item in my Cart, i dont know how

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, don't have enough reputation to comment, that's why writing here.
Looks like you are adding items correctly but in your unit test you try to declare variable `cart` twice which is not allowed:

```
...
var cart = new ListCart();
cart.name = "Mineral Water";
cart.amount = 3;
cart.price = 3000;
entity.Cart.Add(cart);

var cart = new ListCart();
cart.name = "Fried Rice";
cart.amount = 2;
cart.price = 6000;
entity.Cart.Add(cart);
...
```

It won't even compile. Just try to name them differently, like this:

```
...
var cart1 = new ListCart();
cart1.name = "Mineral Water";
cart1.amount = 3;
cart1.price = 3000;
entity.Cart.Add(cart1);

var cart2 = new ListCart();
cart2.name = "Fried Rice";
cart2.amount = 2;
cart2.price = 6000;
entity.Cart.Add(cart2);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think @ochzhen is pointing out the problem correctly.  You're trying to reuse a variable name.  I think a slightly more scalable solution would be to skip using variable names.  You don't need them if you make the constructor call when you call Add and use property initialization.  Try this:

```
    var cart = new ListCart();
    cart.name = "Mineral Water";
    cart.amount = 3;
    cart.price = 3000;
    entity.Cart.Add(new ListCart()
    {
       name = "Mineral Water",
       amount = 3,
       price = 3000
    });
```

Comment: ochzhen's answer is correct.  But, yours is more informative and __more__ correct.  +1